# Is this correct way to Parse inner element of XML by LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Always confused with LINQ to XML. I would like to extract emails as IEnumerable from the following XML.

```
   String xml =@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                   <people>
                     <person firstname=""John"" lastname=""doe"">
                       <contactdetails>
                          <emailaddress>john@unknown.com</emailaddress>
                       </contactdetails>
                     </person> 
                     <person firstname=""Jane"" lastname=""doe"">
                       <contactdetails>
                          <emailaddress>jane@unknown.com</emailaddress>
                           <phonenumber>001122334455</phonenumber>
                         </contactdetails>
                     </person>
                   </people>";
```

After some trials I found the following code works, but I don't like to use ElementAt(0).Value (normally I don't see in other example code). What would be the best way to use LINQ here?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var emails = from p in doc.Descendants("person")
where p.Descendants("emailaddress").Any()
let email =  (string)p.Descendants("emailaddress").ElementAt(0).Value                                      
select email;
```

Comment: Why not `XDocument.Parse(xml).XPathSelectElements("people/person/contactdetails/emailaddress")`? :)

Comment: It isn't about XML. It's about how to use Linq properly to query on collections. If you are sure persons have exactly one `emailaddress`, simply use `p.Descendants("emailaddress").Single().Value`

Answer (score 1):

get all emails from xml

```
var e_mailsAll = doc.Descendants("person")
        .Descendants("emailaddress")
        .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

get first email of each person, if someone has more than 1

```
var e_mailsFirst = doc.Descendants("person")
        .Select(x=>x.Descendants("emailaddress").FirstOrDefault())
        .Where(x=>x!=null)
        .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XPathSelectElements` in order to extract `IEnumerable<XElement>` using XPath:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
   <people>
     <person firstname=""John"" lastname=""doe"">
       <contactdetails>
          <emailaddress>john@unknown.com</emailaddress>
       </contactdetails>
     </person> 
     <person firstname=""Jane"" lastname=""doe"">
       <contactdetails>
          <emailaddress>jane@unknown.com</emailaddress>
           <phonenumber>001122334455</phonenumber>
         </contactdetails>
     </person>
   </people>";

IEnumerable<XElement> elements = XDocument 
    .Parse(xml)
    .XPathSelectElements("people/person/contactdetails/emailaddress");
```

Then, you will be able to use LINQ `Select` in order to extract an array of emails:

```
string[] elements = XDocument 
    .Parse(xml)
    .XPathSelectElements("people/person/contactdetails/emailaddress")
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToArray();
```